# How to send data in batches to a LLM

Tags: batch-processing, openai-api, large-language-model, llama, gpt-4

I have a question on batch processing with LLMs and wanted to see if anyone can help with this.

Is there a way to send data in batches to a LLM to be processed by a GPU? Say for eg. if I wanted to get daily sentiment ratings, rather than sending daily posts to a LLM, is there a way to send 100 days of posts in batches to a LLM to be processed by GPU (so to maximize GPU utilisation, and minimize run time)?

I am looking for a solution for either a closed sourced LLM (like GPT3.5/4) or open sourced LLM (like Llama 2).

Answer (score 0):

If you're running an LLM locally, it is possible to send data in batches. But there are mechanics in inferencing LLMs like "continuous batching" which lead to send single request and let the inference server batch in a "clever" way.

This means you would need to send your whole batch as single requests in parallel to an API like ChatGPT.

Also for open source there are tools like TGI (text generation inference) and vLLM to serve a LLM which has this "clever" batching.

TGI: https://github.com/huggingface/text-generation-inference

vLLM: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do offline inference since you are not doing realtime inference (if I understood your question correctly). You can run vLLM and send all the 100 days data at once. You can find a detailed code in this [blog](https://lightning.ai/lightning-ai/studios/optimized-llm-inference-api-for-mistral-7b-using-vllm?view=public&section=mine)

```py
from vllm import LLM

llm = LLM("mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1", dtype=torch.bfloat16)
```